# PHP in_array and concatenate

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use in_array concatenated in a bootstrap label to determine if its checked or not, but its not working.

This works and echo's 'active' so I know in theory its producing the correct results, but I cant get it to work within my loop

```
echo "<td>";
    echo (in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?'active':'';
echo "</td>";
```

But this wont work and it echoes 'active' outside of the table and breaks up the html

```
foreach($course_data as $course){               
    echo "<tr>";                                                    
        echo "<td data-title='Course Name'>" . $course->course_name . "</td>";
        echo "<td data-title='Icon' class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-lg brand " . $course->course_icon . "' ></i></td>";                                                             
        echo "<td data-title='Renewal Period'>" . $course->renewal_period . " Months</td>";
        echo "<td data-title='Assign'>
                <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>
                    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm' " . (!in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'' . ">
                        <input type='radio' name='course[" . $course->course_id . "]' value='No' autocomplete='off' > No
                    </label>
                    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm' " . (in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'' . ">
                        <input type='radio' name='course[" . $course->course_id . "]' value='Yes' autocomplete='off' > Yes
                    </label>
                </div>                                                              
            </td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";                       
}
```

Cant i use in_array concatenated like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure you're properly formatting output strings when mixing HTML and PHP:

Note: I prefer this syntax instead of echos since it allows HTML highlighting in my IDE

```
foreach($course_data as $course){               
    echo "<tr>";                                                    
        echo "<td data-title='Course Name'>" . $course->course_name . "</td>";
        echo "<td data-title='Icon' class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-lg brand " . $course->course_icon . "' ></i></td>";                                                             
        echo "<td data-title='Renewal Period'>" . $course->renewal_period . " Months</td>";
        echo "<td data-title='Assign'>
                <div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>
                    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm" . (!in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'' ) . "'>
                        <input type='radio' name='course[" . $course->course_id . "]' value='No' autocomplete='off' > No
                    </label>
                    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm" . (in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'') . "'>
                        <input type='radio' name='course[" . $course->course_id . "]' value='Yes' autocomplete='off' > Yes
                    </label>
                </div>                                                              
            </td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";                       
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question above to include the full code

Comment: Thanks for the update but I have to echo everything because its pulled into the view with AJAX

Comment: If you don't echo but just type them outside a PHP block, they are echoed. Just try it.

Comment: No I cant its inside a codeigniter controller, it doesnt work

Comment: Edited again. However I would suggest you look into views and templating, as this is a very good candidate to do that with.

Comment: Thank you. It was brackets that i was missing, I had:  " . `(!in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':''  . "` and i needed `" . (!(in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'' ) . "`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ternary if statement in a string it seems that you have to wrap the whole statement in brackets.

Doesn't work;

```
<label class='btn btn-default btn-sm " . ! in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data) ? 'active' : '' . "'>
        <input type='radio' name='course[" . $course->course_id . "]' value='No' autocomplete='off'> No
</label>
```

Works:

```
<label class='btn btn-default btn-sm " . (! in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data) ? 'active' : '') . "'>
    <input type='radio' name='course[" . $course->course_id . "]' value='No' autocomplete='off'> No
</label>
```

---

Previous answer:

It's hard to tell what's going on because your second code sample doesn't seem to have all of the code involved.

However... something like this should work:

```
$classes = ['btn', 'btn-default', 'btn-sm'];
if (in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data)) {
    $classes[] = 'active';
}
$classesStr = implode(' ', $classes);

echo "<label class='{$classesStr}'>My Label</label>";
```

Comment: I have edited my question above to include the full code

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<label class='btn btn-default btn-sm' " . (!in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'' . ">
//                                        ^ this quote closes your class definition.
```

So, everythnig added after it is not a class, but just some (in)valid html attribute.

Fix is (scroll right):

```
echo "<label class='btn btn-default btn-sm" . (!in_array($course->course_id, $assign_data))?' active':'' . "'>";
//                                                                                                          ^ closin quote now here
```